# Standard Basis Vectors and Subspace Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ are not in the subspace $V$ of $\Bbb R^3$ that is spanned by the two vectors $$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}?$$

I'm not sure what you would do after reducing the augmented matrix. Thanks

Comment: what is the result of your "reducing the augmented matrix"?

Comment: You go through exactly the same process that was explained to you for an almost-identical problem in [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2184135/265466).

Comment: What are $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$? Are you looking for vectors $[ e_1 e_2 e_3]^T$ that are orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Comment: Can't you just compute the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$ which is $v_3=[10 \,\,0 \,\, 5]^T$. Since $v_3$ is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$,  the dot product of any vector $v$ with $v_3$ tells you whether it's in the subspace or not. If the dot product is zero, then $v$ is in the subspace else it's not. For higher dimensions, seems like QR decomposition is the easiest way to find vectors orthogonal to a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Let the vector in the subspace $V$ spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ be $(u,v,w)$.
Now $(u,v,w)$ is the linear combination of $(1,1,-2)$ and $(-2,3,4)$.
i.e. $\beta(1,1,-2)+\mu(-2,3,4)=(u,v,w)$, where $\beta$ and 
$\mu$ are constants.
Hence
\begin{align}
\beta-2\mu &= u &\beta + 3\mu &=v & -2\beta+4\mu&=w
\end{align}
and so $w=-2u$. So the vectors of $V$ should satisfy the above condition.
Among $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ the vectors $e_1$ and $e_3$ are not satisfying this condition . So $e_1$ and $e_3$ are not in $V$.

Comment: Shouldn't your first equation be $\beta - 2\mu=u$?